# Something about the window function

Tags: apache-spark, group-by, window

Something about the window function

as below code, group using window on column `time_test2`.

i want generate group `00:00:00 to next day 00:00:00`, `likes|2017-09-08 00:00:00|2017-09-09 00:00:00|`

but the result from is from `08:00:00 to next day 08:00:00`

why?

how can i sole it?

thanks a lots

the code:

```
Dataset<Row> df3 = df2.groupBy(
            functions.window(df2.col("time_test2"),"1 days"),
            df2.col("info.item_id"),
            df2.col("info.rt")
).count().selectExpr("window.start", "window.end", "item_id", "rt", "count");
```

the schema:

```
root
 |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- item_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- rt: long (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

the result:

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+---+-----+
|              start|                end|item_id| rt|count|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+---+-----+
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      2|  4|   19|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      2|  3|   19|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|     10|  4|   15|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      6|  1|   26|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      1|  3|   25|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      5|  2|   24|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|     10|  1|   15|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      8|  2|   15|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      3|  3|   20|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      3|  4|   20|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      9|  4|   15|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      4|  4|   18|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      5|  1|   24|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      1|  4|   25|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      8|  3|   15|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      6|  3|   26|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      2|  1|   19|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      4|  3|   18|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      1|  2|   25|
|2017-09-08 08:00:00|2017-09-09 08:00:00|      5|  3|   24|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+---+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`functions.window` function is changing the `timestamp` which is out of control as its inbuilt unless you create similar function yourself.

Meanwhile you can use following simple solution

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*
Dataset<Row> df3 = df2.groupBy(
      df2.col("time_test2"),
      df2.col("info.item_id"),
      df2.col("info.rt")
    ).count().select(df2.col("time_test2").as("start"), unix_timestamp(date_add(df2.col("time_test2"), 1),  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS").cast(TimestampType).as("end"), col("item_id"), col("rt"), col("count"));
```

**In Scala**

the process and logic is the same

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df3 = df2.groupBy("time_test2", "info.item_id", "info.rt").count()
.select($"time_test2".as("start"), unix_timestamp(date_add($"time_test2", 1), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS").cast(TimestampType).as("end"), $"item_id", $"rt", $"count")
```